# What is the purpose of the LANGUAGE keyword in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I saw a Haskell source code, and at the beginning of the source file, it included several things like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
```

I know that comments in Haskell stat with `{-` and end with `-}`, but this is clearly something else. What's the purpose of this? It seems pretty similar like `include` statements or macros in C.

Comment: Comments that have those `#` in between like that are pragmas. They have an effect. And there are more than `LANGUAGE` (e.g. `SPECIALIZE`, `INLINE`, `MINIMAL`, and so on). Look [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/pragmas.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose is to enable language extensions. It's a compiler pragma. The GHC compiler supports a lot of language extensions. The [GHC manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/) provides explanation of each extension and examples.

Comment: It might be worth noting that `LANGUAGE` pragmas are intended to be semi-portable. This is not currently very relevant, but it was when Hugs, NHC, etc., were alive.